# JavaScript String Prototype returns Object

Tags: javascript, prototype

When creating a prototype string extension, if I return this directly the result is an object instead of a string.  For instance:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'doSomething', {
    value: function ()
    {
        return this;
    }
});

var r1 = "Hello World";

if (typeof r1 === 'string')
{
    alert('it is a string');
}
else
{
    alert('it is a not string');
}

var r2 = r1.doSomething();

if (typeof r2 === 'string')
{
    alert('it is a string');
}
else
{
    alert('it is a not string');
}
```

results in an alert that says "it is a string" followed by "it is not a string". I know that the string prototype inherits from object, but shouldn't an actual string have the same inheritance chain? Or should I always be calling .toString() before returning this in an extension?

If this is the case, is this true?

```
'hello' !== new String('hello')
```

If so, should we always be calling .toString() if returning this from a string extension method? Should a similar process be followed for other primitive types? Is there a common methodology that could be used for other types as well (e.g. an array extension)?

Comment: Whenever a method is called on a string primitive, the JS environment automatically creates a `String` object to act as the `this` value for the method being called. (This is specified in the ECMAScript spec.)

Comment: So in JavaScript a string object is not the same as var hello = "hello"?

Comment: And if not, will all methods / extensions that normally work on var hello = "hello" work on a this inside of a string prototype extension?

Comment: Please put questions in the question, not as comments. To your first comment: primitives are primitives and objects are objects, so `'hello' !== new String('hello')` but `'hello' == new String('hello')` (the wonders of strict vs abstract equality comparison algorithms). To your second: yes. Prior to ECMAScript Ed 5, *this* had to be an object so primitives are coerced to their related objects. No doubt this behaviour persists to maintain backward compatibility (assuming anyone wanted to change it).

Comment: Hey @RobG - I have updated the question with a few more points